# Почему сайт не проходит проверку на адаптивность?

Tags: html, css, joomla, cms, responsive

Делаю сайт на Joomla 3 шаблон Yoo Nite. Сам шаблон адаптивный. Но, сайт не проходит проверку на https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/. В каком направлении искать решение?

Ссылка на сайт http://gaboarchitects.storno.com.ua/

Comment: Хм...   
Тебе вроде ответила чудо-машина - контент не помещается и ссылки близко.   
Исправь и будет щастье.

Comment: Да, я это видел. Но я firebug'ом просматриваю страницу и не вижу в каких блоках контент не помещаеться. Иначе я б не обращался сюда.

Comment: Как эмулятор не пытается, а ошибка будет.   
Посмотри через мобильное устройство.

Comment: Я смотрел. Проблем не обнаружил

Comment: Хм... И правда всё в порядке.   
Хотя, возможно, у гугла своё вИдение идеала адаптивной вёрстки...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на блоки `.tm-nite-icons > li` и картинки внутри `.tm-nite-icons`.
Для блоков у вас задана фиксированная ширина `282px`. На мобильном разрешении (равном `320px` по ширине), эти блоки выходят за границы экрана и появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки.

Исправить можно так:

```
.tm-nite-icons > li {
    max-width: 282px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Картинки у вас тоже выпадают из ссылки, в которую они обернуты. Все потому, что у вас для ссылки жестко заданы и ширина, и высота. Вы пытаетесь вписать по ширине картинку внутрь ссылки и автоматически вычислить высоту, сохраняя пропорции, но в этом случае пропорции картинок таковы, что подсчитанная высота больше высоты родительского блока. В вашем случае иконки лучше вписывать по высоте. Если не менять верстку, то решение таково:

```
.tm-nite-icons img {
    height: 100%;
    max-width: auto;
}
```

Как альтернативный вариант можно использовать (и я бы советовал так и сделать) свойство `background-image` и `background-size` для ссылки и полностью избавиться от вложенных картинок.

Кроме того, при наведении ваши иконки масштабируются и залезают на следующий за ними заголовок `h1`, частично перекрывая его. К слову, `h1` должен быть один на странице.

Еще обратите внимание на слайдер в самом низу. Мало того, что на маленьком разрешении ваши 5 картинок в ряд выглядят слишком мелкими, так и кнопки управления (вперед/назад) сильно смещены вниз, перекрывая нижний край контейнера со слайдами.

Подобных недочетов на сайте довольно много и все их описывать здесь смысла нет.
Я рекомендую вам разбить сайт на логические блоки (шапка/слайдер/иконки/карусель/подвал) и заниматься отладкой каждого из них по отдельности, проверяя промежуточный результат упомянутым вами инструментом от Google.

Ну и напоследок рекомендую вам перепроверить выезжающее слева меню в мобильном отображении. Оно не закрывает экран на 100%.